# Liferay from fileentry to java file object

Tags: java, file, liferay, document-library

Anyone know how to retrieve a contentStream from a `DLFileEntry` (http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/DLFileEntry.html) using an httpservlet?

I tried using `DLFileEntry.getContentStream()` but it fails giving me the error

```
com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException: PermissionChecker not initialized
```

I solved in part that problem setting hardcode my userId:

```
long userId=2

            PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(userId);

            User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(userId);

            PermissionChecker permissionChecker;

                permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(user, false);

            PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
```

**The problem of this solution is how to get the real userId, and how happen if the user is a guest?**

I tried Long.parseLong(req.getRemoteUser()); but fail also.

Comment: Can you add code on how the DLFileEntry is delegated to the FileEntryAdapter?

Comment: Are you trying to access this Document Library via a service? Also what version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 3):

```
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFile(userId, fileEntryId, version, incrementCounter)
```

gives you the File. Did you try using this?

Comment: This will only give you the file if your DocumentLibrary implementation supports it. I know that S3 & JCR don't support this method, and will throw "Unsupported Operation Exceptions" if you try to use it in Liferay 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Liferay 6.1 then the following code will get you a InputStream for the That DLFileEntry.

```
InputStream inputStream = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(fileEntry.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileEntryId(), fileEntry.getVersion());
```

Howwever the error you're getting is seems to be due you not authenticating with Liferay before making this call to the server.

How are you calling this code?

Comment: But how are you calling this code? In a portlet? Is the user running it logged in or a guest? Is it being accessed externally? I've never needed to use a PermissionCheck to do the above, but it does require a Service Context to get the DLFileEntry.

Comment: I create a servlet to download zip file, It works but I need to set the permission of my user in the code.. I think is very strange..

Comment: By servlet do you mean Portlet?

Answer (score 0):

Please use PermissionThreadLocal.getPermissionChecker() to get the permissionChecker object of the current logged in user with current state. If the user is guest, still you will get the permissionChecker object.

-Felix

Comment: Hi Felix, I'm sorry but your solution doesn't work it still give the same error..

Comment: Hi Sabrina, I would suggest you to use PortletServlet instead of HttpServlet, when you use PortletServlet, you will have a portlet context, and from there you will get portlet request, portlet session and hopefully permission checker part.